# Exporting Excel Tabs to Separate PDF File - Skip 1st 3 Tabs

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

New to VBA coding in Excel, and trying to figure out how to revise my current code (see below). It creates a PDF for each of my tabs, but I simply want it to ignore the 1st 3 tabs where I have my work and only create PDFs starting with the 4th tab. I'm sure it's any easy addition to define the scope, but can't pinpoint exactly how to code it.

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()
' PDF Export Macro
' Change C:\Exports\ to your folder path where you need the files saved
' Save Each Worksheet to a separate PDF file.

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
nm = ws.Name

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="File Location" & nm & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help that you all can give.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you only working on ActiveSheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the sheets you want to skip are indexes 1, 2, and 3, you can use a `For` loop to skip those, and start on worksheet 4:

```
Sub exportToPDF()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim nm As String

For i = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        nm = .Name
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:="File Location" & nm & ".pdf", _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce! That seemed to do the trick. Appreciate the help!